# How tell tell javadoc that my period doesn't end a sentence

Tags: javadoc

javadoc uses the first "sentence" of a doc comment as a summary sentence.  It assumes that a period followed by a space, tab, or line terminator ends the sentence.  Suppose I want an abbreviation like "e.g." or "etc." in my summary; is there a way to tell javadoc not to treat it as the end of a sentence?  I can replace the period with `&#x2e;` but I'm wondering if there's a less ugly way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to avoid periods in the first sentence. In [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) it's suggested that you should replace the space character as a workaround:

> ```
>  /**
>  * This is a simulation of Prof.&nbsp;Knuth's MIX computer.
>  */
>
>  /**
>   * This is a simulation of Prof.<!-- --> Knuth's MIX computer.
>   */
> ```

Personally, I would just omit the dot if I couldn't avoid abbreviations altogether.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely better than the hack I came up with.  I'm pretty particular about spelling things korrecktlee so omitting the dot isn't really an option for me.

Comment: @ajb I haven't tested it but maybe you can also [input the non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods) directly, without using the html entity.